# Evaluate $\sum^{100}_{k=1}[{1 \over k}-{1\over k+1}]$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

> Evaluate $$\sum^{100}_{k=1}[{1 \over k}-{1\over k+1}]$$

I've tried:

$$\sum^{100}_{k=1}[{1 \over k}-{1\over k+1}]
\\= \sum^{100}_{k=1} k^{-1}-(k+1)^{-1}
\\= {2 \over n(n+1)}-({n(n+1)\over 2}+1)^{-1}
\\ = {2 \over 100(101)}-({100(101) \over 2} +1)^{-1}
\\ = {1 \over 5050}-{1 \over 5051}$$

Apparently this is wrong.

I have a feeling that using negative exponent to flip the fraction is incorrect. why?

Could someone show me the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Try computing the same sum, but form $k = 1$ to $k = 4$, and just writing out all the terms (without doing any simplification of fractions). I think you'll notice something.

Comment: You confused $\sum (k^{-1})$ with $(\sum k)^{-1}$, which are ***very*** different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $n$ instead of $100$ to keep it general. Write the sum as
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}.
$$
The second last equality comes from cancelling terms in the telescoping series (e.g. $-1/2$ and $+1/2$, etc.). The only terms that **do not "pair" with any other terms are the first and the last**: $1$ and $1/(n+1)$.

If we plug in $n=100$,
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{100}{101}=0.\overline{9900}.
$$